# Error message showing after cleannig inputs with Vue

Tags: vue.js

I have a simple form to update a password with 3 inputs (old_password, new_password and new_password_confirmation).

After the submit, if it is updated successfully, the inputs are cleaned. The problem is that after this, the input errors are showed even when the conditional is false.

This is one of the inputs:

```
<input type="password" v-model="old_password">
<small class="text-danger" v-if="errors.old_password != ''">{{errors.old_password}}</small>
```

The logic:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            old_password: '',
            errors: []
        }
    },
    watch: {
        old_password(value) {
            this.old_password = value

            if(value.length < 3) {
                this.errors.old_password = 'Debes ingresar al menos 4 caracteres'
            } else {
                this.errors.old_password = ''
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updatePassword() {
            this.$store.dispatch('updatePassword', data)
            .then(response => {
                this.old_password = ''
                this.errors.old_password = ''
            })
            .catch(error => {
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because once input becomes empty your condition `value.length < 3` is true and error will be shown

Simply add to your condition this one `&& value.length > 0`
So the final code will look like

```
if(value.length < 3 && value.length > 0) {
  this.errors.old_password = 'Debes ingresar al menos 4 caracteres'
} else {
  this.errors.old_password = ''
}
```

Also, `errors` should be an object instead of an array - `errors: {}`